# jQuery $ You must select a selector bypassing others

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm using jQuery. It is necessary to refer to the class selector .potatoes:

```
$('.apple .potatoes')
```

But it is within selector class .orange should not be selected.

```
<div class="apple">
     <div class="orange">
            <div class="potatoes" title="dont touch me">dont touch me</div>
     </div>
     <div class="potatoes" title="return to Me">return to Me</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the direct [child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors):

```
$('.apple > .potatoes')
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the [children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/) function:

```
$('.apple').children('.potatoes')
```